# How to pass Apache environment variable to url in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-env

I am setting a apache environment variable through php function, [**apache_setenv**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-setenv.php).

```
apache_setenv("EXAMPLE_VAR", "Example Value");
```

But I am having problem accessing this variable inside `.htaccess` I am not able to use this env variable inside .htaccess in anyway. but I can access it through php `getenv()`.

And problem is not only by setting variable through php I am unable to access env variable set by `.htaccess` itself.

I've tried

Suppose env variable to be `www.domain.com`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ^(.*)$ test.php?id=%{ENV:VARIABLE} [L]
```

&

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:VARIABLE} ^www.(.+)
RewriteRule ^ test.php?id=%1 [L]
```

And similar other test to just verify that env variable are set and functioning.

Mod_env and mod_rewrite is on.

Comment: An interesting problem ++

Comment: A parent process (Apache) cannot access environment variables changed or set in a child process (PHP).

Comment: PHP module is invoked after mod_rewrite module has completed it's run hence changed made via PHP are not seen in rewrite rules.

Comment: @anubhava @OlafDietsche But I am having issue even after setting them in `.htaccess`, I am unable to grasp the concept of env variable in `.htaccess`. and if I cannot access them in `.htaccess` what is the existence of apache_setenv serving here?

Comment: `apache_setenv ` is PHP function. How are you setting a variable in .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava Using SetEnv VAR /foo/bin above rewrite rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable set using `SetEnv` directives are not seen by `mod_rewrite` due to sequence of module loading by Apache. Use `SetEnvIf` instead like that:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^ VAR=/foo/bin
```

Then use it in `mod_rewrite` rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:VAR} =/foo/bin
RewriteRule ^home/?$ /something [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I got some other ideas from this as well.